# Java ClassCastException: How Come?

Tags: java, casting, broadcastreceiver, classcastexception

I am trying to end a call using the Android Telephony Manager (the new Call Screening API is not appropriate for me). I found many examples on the web, all very similar to my code below. It compiles just fine but I get a runtime ClassCastException on the line

```
telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
```

The exception is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
  com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy
  cannot be cast to com.ramrod.MyApp.IncomingCallReceiver$ITelephony
```

My code is

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ITelephony telephonyService;
        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                    if ((number != null)) {
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, "Ring " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Answered " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Idle "+ number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The examples I've found also direct inclusion of the Java interface as shown below:

```
public static interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```

What causes this type of exception? How can I fix it?
(I'm very suspicious of the added interface).

I've also tried importing *com.android.internal.telephony* (which includes ITelephony), but that doesn't complie.

Comment: This type of exception happens when the object you are casting (an instance of `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy`) is not an instance of the type you are casting to (`com.ramrod.MyApp.IncomingCallReceiver$ITelephony`). In particular, observe that `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` and `com.ramrod.MyApp.IncomingCallReceiver$ITelephony` are two different types with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles because you use reflection : `Object Method.invoke()`.
Reflection is often nice at compile time but may be less at runtime.

Here, the instance that you try to cast is at runtime `Proxy`, more precisely the nested class : `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.Stub.Proxy`.

The interface `ITelephony` that you defined as nested class of `MyApp.IncomingCallReceiver` is not an instance of that `Proxy` class. That is sure as it extends nothing :

```
public static interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```

Whereas the class cast exception.

I suppose that `Proxy` is a generated implementation of `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony`, so what you need to do is probably just import that class and to cast to this class :

```
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;
//..    
telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
```